# Blazor WebAssembly caching on IIS

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, no-cache

I have migrated my Blazor project from net5 to net6.

However, I get the following error when launching the website:

> Uncaught (in promise) error: could not find class: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting:EntrypointInvoker in assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly

I have learned from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38436 that I might have an issue with caching the `blazor.webassembly.js` in the browser.

The file `blazor.webassembly.js` should be served without caching it (cache-control: no-cache).

However, the file is not served with the corresponding header:

[image]

It is not a blazor webassembly .NET Core hosted, but a simple static website, hosted with IIS. Is there a specific setting on IIS or elsewhere that I am missing?

Comment: How did you migrate your Blazor project? Or you can try to redeploy your Blazor project to iis.

Comment: I have created a new project and moved all the components to the new project, as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#blazor. This is not an issue about the migration, it is only a general issue about configuring caching in IIS.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this message, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.